# Cannot boot into EOS, in recovery mode no keyboard

Tags: boot

I used boot-repair, but still the boot is stuck. When i use the recovery mode i cannot enter the password to decrypt the partition because the keyboard don't work. I tried all kernels and I tried 3 Keyboards, different USB Ports and i also changed the BIOS settings to legacy mode and csm and legacy USB mode but still no keyboards works to enter the password. I have a USB Stick with EOS which boots fine and in test mode i can unlock the encrypted partition. Is it possible to repair the corrupt EOS installation from outside. In other words from the terminal in test mode?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I decrypted the whole partition so that i can boot at least in recovery mode but it still dont finish booting. It stops at the Busybox shell (initramfs) waiting for a command. I am a newbie and the problem started when i was tired and was trying to fix a problem where i could not update a kernel i think because the swap drive where they are stored was full of older kernels and there was no enough diskspace left for the update. The terminal gave me infos i should edit a file, which name i forgot, but something about initram. I was getting a bit impatient while reading some forumthreads about those things, and did some terminal commands trying to delete old kernels as far as i remember and since then i am unable too boot. It would be nice if someone could help me to repair the system. I backed up my files, but the environment and programs and tools i worked with would need a new setup, which would take a lot of time.

[image]